# Set user permissions | Artisan command will not run in code but works fine on command line

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, permissions

I have a route that is essentially a "hook" to run an Artisan command, it accepts some `get` parameters as arguments:

```
Route::get('hook', function()
{
  $param = Input::get('param');
  Artisan::call('myCommand', array('param' => $param));
}
```

`myCommand` simply creates a directory in the root called `param` and a `hello.txt` file.

I can run `myCommand` fine using `php artisan myCommand param1` and it works as expected. I can also use Artisan's `tinker` command and run `Artisan::call()` perfectly fine too.

However when I try the command via visiting the URL (e.g. `example.com/hook&param=hello`), my command does not create anything as expected. If it helps as well, I'm trying this on Laravel Forge. On my local dev machine everything works fine.

Any idea what is wrong?

Comment: Sounds like a permission problem. HTTP server usually runs as `www-data` when you execute the command you are logged in as the owner of the directory. Thus, you can create the file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can either set permissions to the folder by

```
chmod 777 -R /path/to/folder
```

**what you absolutely shouldn't do, as everybody can write and execute everything in this directory afterwards**

or, what I would prefer, you create a new group, let's call it usergroup:

```
sudo groupadd usergroup
```

Now that the group exists, add the two users to it:

```
sudo usermod -a -G usergroup <your username>
sudo usermod -a -G usergroup www-data
```

Now all that's left is to set the permissions on the directory:

```
sudo chgrp -R usergroup /path/to/the/directory
sudo chmod -R 770 /path/to/the/directory     // <<<<<< change this to 775
```

Now only members of the usergroup group can read, write, or execute files and folders within the directory. Note the `-R` argument to the `chmod` and `chgrp` commands: this tells them to recurse into every sub directory of the target directory and modify every file and directory available.

You may also want to change 770 to something like 774 if you want others to be able to read the files, 775 if you want others to read and execute the files, etc. Group assignment changes won't take effect until the users log out and back in.

In your case, you should definately change it to 775 afterwards...

Answer (score 2):

You need to set up directory permissions correctly.

`sudo chown -R <YOUR_USERNAME>:www-data <THE_DIRECTORY>`

Comment: Are there any alternatives to this? I'd like to keep code on both environments exact, I'd have to ssh into my droplet and run this every time.

Comment: No you only have to run this one time for each machine you have. Get used to doing things like this.

Comment: I'm not too familiar with DevOps stuff... getting `chmod: invalid mode: ‘forge:www-data’` error.

Comment: Are you in a bash shell? Is it an actual machine or is there a proxy between you and your machine? I'm not familiar with "forge".

Comment: Yes I'm in a bash shell with ssh access to my server right now.