# Delete permissions for uploaded file in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, file-upload, laravel-5, image-uploading

I have a directory called `photos` with `read, write & delete permissions` for itself and it's enclosed items.

I use the `Laravel's` method `move()` in order to upload the file inside the directory i mentioned above. The upload process is finishing without any errors, but my problem is that the permissions of each uploaded file are limited and i cannot use the Laravel's `delete()` method so i can completely remove the uploaded file from my directory.

Comment: make sure that your www-data user has permissions to the folders you need to work on. See my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27074370/set-user-permissions-artisan-command-will-not-run-in-code-but-works-fine-on-co/27074580#27074580 for how-to